# Issue Converting Processing (JAVA based library) into P5.JS code (ECMAScript based library)

Tags: processing, p5.js, transpiler

I am having issues converting a piece of JAVA based code into ECMAScript/TypeScript, may someone can help. There are two parts I struggle to convert a) a constructor overload I think and b) a self referencing push. Maybe there is a different way to write this?

```
class Finder {
  PVector location;
  PVector velocity;
  float diameter;
  Pvector origin = new PVector(width / 2, height/2);

  Finder(int x, int y) {
    location = new PVector(width/2, height/2);
    velocity = new PVector(x, y);
    diameter = 8;
  }

  // this is a) where I struggle to convert
  Finder(Finder parent) {
    location = parent.location.get();
    velocity = parent.velocity.get();
    float area = PI*sq(parent.diameter/2);
    float newDiam = sqrt(area/2/PI)*2;
        
    diameter = newDiam;
    parent.diameter = newDiam;
  }

  void update() {
    if(origin.dist(location)> 300){
            // nothing
        } else if (diameter>0.5) {
                location.add(velocity);
                PVector bump = new PVector(random(-1, 1), random(-1, 1));
                bump.mult(0.1);
                velocity.add(bump);
                velocity.normalize();
            
                if (random(0, 1)<0.02) {
                    // this is b) where I struggle to convert
                    paths = (Finder[]) append(paths, new Finder(this));
                }
            }
        }
}

Finder[] paths;
```

Answer (score 2):

Regarding **part a**, treat is a function that returns a copy (new instance with copied properties from argument instance):

(JS doesn't support overloaded constructors, hence simply using a method instead of a constructor should suffice)

e.g.

```js
copy(parent) {
    location = parent.location.copy();
    velocity = parent.velocity.copy();
    let area = PI*sq(parent.diameter/2);
    let newDiam = sqrt(area/2/PI)*2;
        
    diameter = newDiam;
    // this looks a bit sus to me: why should we change the parent ? 
    parent.diameter = newDiam;
  }
```

Regarding **part b** I can infer that `paths` is a `Finder[]` in the global scope (e.g. main sketch variables). Is so, that will be a plain js array when you port to p5.js and in js arrays are dynamic so you should be able to simply do use `paths.push(this.copy())` instead.

(If you want to test in the Processing sketch, swap the `Finder[] paths` line to `ArrayList<Finder> paths = new ArrayList<Finder>()` and use `paths.add(New Finder(this));` instead `paths = (Finder[]) append(paths, new Finder(this));`)

Comment: Hi George, thank you so much. And as well for the comments, I learned something new and the sketch is working perfectly in p5.JS now. 